# Determining Detail Disclosure Touch on a Xamarin.iOS Map Annotation

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am writing a map view/annotation editor for an Xamarin.iOS app. I have:

```
public class MapEditorDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate { ... }
```

In the GetViewForAnnotation override, I make this call to put a DetailDisclosure button on the callout:

```
pinView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType( UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure );
```

This works fine, I get my call out with the Detail Disclosure showing. I am able to receive the touch notification on my annotation's callouts by:

```
public override void CalloutAccessoryControlTapped(MKMapView mapView, MKAnnotationView view, UIControl control) { ... }
```

But when I click the annotation, how I find out if they clicked the Detail Disclosure button and not just the annotation?

Thanks.

Comment: If user taps just the annotation, it should only call didSelectAnnotationView.  It should only call calloutAccessoryControlTapped if the left or right accessory views are tapped.  Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: DidSelectAnnotationView fires when the pin is selected before the annotation popup appears.  CalloutAccessoryControlTapped is fired any time the annotation is clicked, whether it is the text of the annotation or the DetailDisclosure button.

Comment: You mean where the title text is on the callout (by annotation I mean the part you tap to bring up the callout).  Yes, I think iOS 7 calls the calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method if you tap anywhere on the callout.  I don't think there's an easy way to avoid that.  However, if you have both left and right views, you can check if the control parameter is equal to the left or right view.

Comment: Ok, I'll just have to live with this functionality.  As overriding it wouldn't be the way the user expects it to behave.  Thanks - El